# Filter backgrid data table by Date column

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, backgrid

I have a backgrid data table with some columns like id, name, user_creation_date and i have a datetime picker widget. How can i create a custom filter to filter the results based on a specific user_creation_date date value?

Searched the web but found nothing about it
This is the default searchbar code

```
                // Search Bar
                var requestsTableFilter = new Backgrid.Extension.ClientSideFilter({
                    collection: monitoring.requestsPaged,
                    fields: null
                });
                $("#requestsTable").before(requestsTableFilter.render().el);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want server side filter, You can refer to the example mentioned in the backgrid.js official page:

http://backgridjs.com/ref/extensions/filter.html